# Why jQuery.fler plugin is not delete image using Ajax / PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using following plugin to upload image.

**Plugin url:**

http://filer.grandesign.md/

Once it's uploaded the image it's showing me preview and there are a delete icon to delete uploaded image. Like bellow image : (See red bucket icon)

[image]

**This plugin use following php code to delete the upload file :**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['file'])){
    $file = 'images/menu_images/' . $_POST['file'];
    if(file_exists($file)){
        unlink($file);
        echo 'file deleted';        
    }
}
?>
```

**What I am doing Now :**

When I upload the image I renamed the uploaded image and save to a folder called : `images/menu_images/`

But when I try to delete the uploaded file it's not deleting the file because I renamed the original uploaded file and save it to a folder.

So to solve this issue I am using following php code to `print/echo` the `image name`, `product id (p_id)`, and `user id (u_id)`

**See this line : echo $all_images.'|'.$session_last_id.'|'.$u_id;**

```
$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['files'] as $k => $l) {
   foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
       if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
           $files[$i] = array();
       $files[$i][$k] = $v;
   }
}

foreach ($files as $file) {

    $handle = new upload($file);
    $file = $file['name'];
    $ext  = explode('.', $file);
    $ext = $ext[1];

    if ($handle->uploaded) {

        $handle->file_new_name_body     = 'mpic_list_'.uniqid('', true);
        $menu_list_image = $handle->file_new_name_body.'.'.$ext;

        $handle->image_resize          = true;
        $handle->image_ratio_crop      = true;
        $handle->image_x               = 360;
        $handle->image_y               = 240;   

        $handle->process('images/menu_images/');    

        $handle->file_new_name_body     = 'mpic_small_'.uniqid('', true);
        $menu_small_image = $handle->file_new_name_body.'.'.$ext;

        $handle->image_resize          = true;
        $handle->image_ratio_crop      = true;  
        $handle->image_x               = 100;
        $handle->image_y               = 65;

        $handle->process('images/menu_images/');

        $handle->file_new_name_body     = 'mpic_large_'.uniqid('', true);
        $menu_large_image = $handle->file_new_name_body.'.'.$ext;

        $handle->image_resize          = true;
        $handle->image_ratio_crop      = true;  
        $handle->image_x               = 700;
        $handle->image_y               = 470;

        $handle->process('images/menu_images/');

        if ($handle->processed) {           
            $all_images = $menu_list_image . $menu_small_image . $menu_large_image;
            $u_id = (int) $_SESSION['logged_user_id'];

            if(!isset($_SESSION['last_id'])) {
                // insert upload image section data...
                $insert_menu_details = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO products (p_id) VALUES ('')");
                $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                $insert_upload_image = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO product_images VALUES ('', '$menu_large_image', '$menu_list_image', '$menu_small_image', '$last_id', '$u_id')");    
                $_SESSION['last_id'] = $last_id;

                $all_images = "$menu_large_image";
                echo $all_images.'|'.$last_id.'|'.$u_id;
            } else {
                // update upload image section data
                $session_last_id = $_SESSION['last_id'];
                $update_upload_image = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO product_images VALUES ('', '$menu_large_image', '$menu_list_image', '$menu_small_image', '$session_last_id', '$u_id')");    

                $all_images = "$menu_large_image";
                echo $all_images.'|'.$session_last_id.'|'.$u_id;
            }



            $handle->clean();
        } else {
            //echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }   
}
```

**And then, In ajax success method I am using following code to get the printed image name, product id and user id to call another ajax method to delete individual uploaded image:**

```
success: function(data, el){

var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();

el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){

    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success <a id=\"deleteImage\">Delete Me</a></div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow").each(function() {

        $('#deleteImage').on('click', function() {
            var params = data.split('|');
            var url = "delete_upload_image?p1=" + params[0] +"&p2=" + params[1] + "&p3=" + params[2];
            // Make AJAX call as you want to url
            $.get(url);
        }); 
    }) 
});
```

**But the problem is :**

1) When I click on `delete me` link to delete the uploaded image it's delete all images from database BUT it's should be delete only my selected image

In Console log It's calling Ajax 3 time !! but ti's should be 1 ajax call : Like bellow :

[image]

2) You see that there are 3 uploaded image on picture. I can only call ajax on first uploaded image but can't call ajax on other 2 uploaded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have three images there, and then in your code there is:

```
$('#deleteImage').on('click',
```

done in a forEach loop. Instead of adding click handler to a single image, you add it to all images every time. So, with 3 images, you get 3 click handlers for each click event, thus you are calling AJAX 3 times - once per attached click handler.

Try to change your code, so it does not attach click handlers in a loop. Refactor it, so it is done outside of loop, just once OR maybe use something like this:

```
$('#deleteImage', $(this)).on('click',
```

To set it just once, find parent tag for all of those images and call something like that, once on initialization, instead:

```
$($parentOfAllImages).on('click', '#deleteImage',
```

Comment: let me try with this

Comment: I would try implementing click handler on parent of all images.

Comment: You know. In this plugin to delete the image it's asking user to confirmation. Now when I delete its also show me confirmation alert. I want to call ajax when user click Yes but now it's calling the ajax when confirmation is showing. Can I fix it ?

Comment: According to their documentation (http://filer.grandesign.md/#documentation), you can set `onRemove` handler. Maybe try using that, instead of setting custom click handlers. You would have to set some custom data on elements (instead of click handlers) and possibly call AJAX from `onRemove` (and maybe return false from it, so filer will not continue its own handling? but i don't know how it works - i never used it).

Comment: Sorry, after checking https://github.com/CreativeDream/jQuery.filer/blob/master/js/jquery.filer.js it looks like returning `false` from `onRemove` will do nothing. But maybe filer does not send any AJAX when "removing" files? Maybe it just removes them from UI, which would be good in this situation, because you could safely send own AJAX calls.